# How do you clear objects between JUnit/Maven tests?

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, junit

I'm testing different parts of a miniature search engine, and some of the JUnit tests are leaving entries in the index that interfere with other tests. Is there a convention in JUnit/Maven for clearing objects between tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 particular annotations that can help you with this, and are intended to be used in cases such as yours:

`@After` defines that a certain method must be executed after every `@Test`, while `@AfterClass` is the method to execute once the entire test class has been executed. Think of the latter as a last cleanup method to purge any structures or records you've been using and sharing between tests so far.

Here is an example:

```
@After
public void cleanIndex() {
    index.clear(); //Assuming you have a collection
}

@AfterClass
public void finalCleanup() {
    //Clean both the index and, for example, a database record.
}
```

**Note**: They have their counterparts (`@Before` and `@BeforeClass`) that to exactly the opposite by invoking the related methods before a `@Test` method and before starting to execute the `@Test`s defined on that class. This ones are the `setUp` used in previous versions of JUnit.

---

If you can't use annotations, the alternative is to use the good old `tearDown` method:

```
public void tearDown() {
    index.clear(); //Assuming you have a collection.
}
```

This is provided by the JUnit framework and behaves like a method annotated with `@After`.

Answer (score 1):

You should make use of the @Before annotation to guarantee that each test is running from a clean state.  Please see: [Test Fixtures](http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/faq/faq.htm#tests_2).

Answer (score 1):

Inside of your junit testing class, you can override the methods `setup` and `teardown`. `setup` will run before every one of your tests while `teardown` will run after every single junit test that you have.

ex:

```
public class JunitTest1 {

    private Collection collection;

    //Will initialize the collection for every test you run
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        collection = new ArrayList();
        System.out.println("@Before - setUp");
    }

    //Will clean up the collection for every test you run
    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        collection.clear();
        System.out.println("@After - tearDown");
    }

    //Your tests go here
}
```

This is useful for clearing out data inbetween tests, but also allows you to not have to reinitialize your fields inside of every single test.